# Woocommerce/Wordpress: Featured Image/Product loading with background image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I'm having a problem with my product image loading with the background image. An example to what Im referring to can be found here https://www.dontcursekids.com/product/not-for-kids-tee-2/ .

I have tried deleting the product image from each individual product (which I'm assuming works the same way a featured image works) and it disappeared from the product's page background. However, it also deletes the thumbnail on the shop page and replaces it with a default picture. I've tried numerous ways with CSS, and several plugins, but I still can't remove it from the background of the product page, and keep my thumbnail of for the preview. ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the sourcecode on line 233, that's where the background image is set. You can remove that line in inspector (right click -> inspector in firefox/chrome), and you will see that it goes away, which will tell you that this line is the problem. I don't know how this line got there or how you've tried to edit css (through plugins?), but I assume somehow you injected that line of code there, or it could be in your theme files. Either way, this is the line you have to delete.

Comment: I see exactly what you're saying. I looked at it inspector and clicked on the background image. Its has a link for the product image as one background. Then it has the image that actually have for the background, but with a strike though. I'm guessing some how its picking the product image/featured image as the background for some odd reason. I'm still lost but a few steps closer because of your help thank you.

Comment: The image you actually have has a strike through because the other background property has the tag `!important`.

Comment: I added the code below to the CSS customizer and while it helped remove the product image from the background, it just shows a black background. Instead of the original image which has the strike through. Is there a tag I'm missing, or a better code to remove the importnat off the product image.                                                         

    .woocommerce  {
    background-image:none !important
}

Comment: I'd recommend solving this issue not by adding more css but by removing css that shouldn't be there. It's best to remove all background properties that apply to that background, except the correct one. Else it will become a huge mess and you'll run into many more problems in the future. It sounds like you're adding css in several places. If you stick to one, that would surely help maintaining an organized overview.

Comment: All the additional CSS added was removed before I posted. I tested it then deleted. Its not happening across the site, but just inside the products page which is bundled into the woocommerce plugin. Adding the code in comment remove the background from every page/post inside of woocommerce, but left the desired background image. I'm thinking it must be a tag I'm using or some template that needs to be edited to remove the product image as important. So the desired image loads correctly.

Comment: I looked further and see that the code is in the index of the product page. I'm trying find a way to edit, and remove the important but unfortunately I don't think its possible. Unless I'm  missing something. Appreciate your help though you helped a lot.

Comment: if you add another product, is this new product then showing its own featured image as background? Or is it showing the featured image of the old product as background? Or is it showing the black background you intend? In the first and second case, the css line is somehow appended to the product page file. Either in php (possible in the first case, because it's dynamic) or in some other file it loads (through a plugin for example). In the third case, it must arise somewhere in the post data, which is most likely due to something you set somewhere in the dashboard.

Comment: I figured it out after removing all the css, and contacting woocomerece.  For some odd reason, a background manager plugin was changing the product image to the background.  It couldn't be deleted because I didn't have access to the index file of the product pages in my editor or on my cpanal. Deleting the plugin changed the layout of site, but immediately fixed the issue. thanks for your help. Marked your suggestion as solution.